# How to Check the Hashmap's First element?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
  if(callingflag)
            {
                int calledUserTp = totalPointsByUserid(callinguserid,jokercard);
                System.out.println("Total Points of the User Who has made a Call is ::"+calledUserTp);

            HashMap<Integer,Integer> useridTotalRankMap = totalPointsforEveryUser(jokercard);
            HashMap<Integer,Integer> useridTotalRankMapSorted = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
            useridTotalRankMapSorted = (HashMap<Integer, Integer>) sortByComparator(useridTotalRankMap);
            for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry :useridTotalRankMapSorted.entrySet())
            {
                System.out.println( entry.getKey() +"----"+entry.getValue());
                if(entry.getKey() == callinguserid )
                {
                    System.out.println( "GOOD CALL");
                    break;
                }

            }
    }
```

How can I avoid the for loop mentioned above .
useridTotalRankMapSorted is a Map

I have this hashmap called useridTotalRankMap  it will have  userid with some totalpoints.

I want to check if the value corresponding to calleruserid  is the least in that hashmap provided there are no ties.

say ther is

```
1:4
4:7
3:7
2:5
```

and calleruserid = 1 . I print "good call" if the value of key=1 ie 4 is the minimum.

Hope I am clear now.

is there any change in the way I am coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)s do not guarantee order.

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

*From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html*

---

To maintain insertion order, you should use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is
>   normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map
>   (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key
>   is re-inserted into the map.

*From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html*

---

To maintain a *sort* order (natural sort ordering, or as defined by a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)), you should use any class that implements [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

> A Map that further provides a total ordering on its keys. The map is
>   ordered according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a
>   Comparator typically provided at sorted map creation time. This order
>   is reflected when iterating over the sorted map's collection views

*From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html*

Comment: Can you see the edits I have made . So that you can help me to this situation

Comment: "I print "good call" if the value of key=1 ie 4 is the minimum." Just to clarify: you're checking that the *key* (1) is the minimum, right?  Not the *value* (4)?  If this is the case, you should use a `SortedMap`.

Comment: I am checking value 4 is the minimum. And I need to ensure 4 is not duplicated. In case there is another 4 then I need to choose the key based on priority(that will be another alogorithm)

Comment: There is no (built-in) way to sort by the value in a map.  You have to either iterate through the collection, or flip the map around (make the keys the values and vice versa).

Comment: I do have a method which will sort the hashmap based on the values.

My question is to compare the calleduser Value with the values in the hashmap .(I want the succss call when the calleruser is the minimum value)

Comment: (1) Use a `LinkedHashMap`, as it guarantees ordering whereas a `HashMap` does not.  Then you can get the first one by using any of the methods used in the other answers you see here. (2) It really seems like you should consider a redesign; the benefit of maps really comes from working with the keys, not the values.  The solution would be simpler and cleaner if you had a map (or maybe, in this situation, a [multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap)) of the ranks to the users.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14434/discussion-between-meenakshi-and-jonathan-newmuis)

Answer (score 5):

A HashMap is not sorted. It has no *first* element.

Answer (score 3):

Use `useridTotalRankMapSorted.entrySet().iterator().next()` to access the first item. Better make sure you **are** indeed using a sorted map!

Comment: HashMaps are not sorted maps.

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis Thank you for that comment. You never know, maybe OP consistently managed to overlook all the answers surrounding mine.

Comment: Whatever your `sortByComparator` method looks like, it surely doesn't have the effect that you want. Apparently you want to sort by value (rank); you shouldn't use a map at all for that. You may put all the map's entries into a list and then sort that list with a suitable comparator.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with sorted `Map`s like `TreeMap`, and the easiest way to get the first element would be with the iterator (if you want to hold the insertion order `LinkedHashMap`):

```
Map m = new TreeMap(); // get it from somewhere else otherwise it doesn't make sense
Set s = m.entrySet();
Iterator i = s.iterator();
if (i.hasNext()) {
    Object firstElement = i.next();
}
```

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` is not a *sorted* map. It is a map that maintains the insertion or access order.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a `LinkedHashMap` to get the first inserted element

Then ->

```
useridTotalRankMapSorted.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey()
useridTotalRankMapSorted.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `HashMap` is a **class** which **do Not implement** `Sorted Map` **Interface**.

**2.** Use`TreeMap` if you want to **fetch the data in Order.**

**3.** Use `LinkedHashMap` if you want nodes linked to each other and then fetch the 1st element.

Answer (score 0):

First, as everybody else said, HashMap is not sorted.

Second, as key in Map is unique (can't map key to more than one value).

Why don't you just get from the map (`map.get(callinguserId)`), what did you gain by iterating on entries ?

That if will only be true once anyway.